# ¿Cómo sumar los valores de una lista y el resultado agregarlo a un diccionario?

Tags: python-3.x

Me estoy iniciando en Python. Tengo el siguiente problema, de un diccionario llamado ventas necesito sumar las ventas por trimestre y agregar el resultado a un diccionario de trimestres, que me muestre las ventas del t1,t2,t3 y t4. Esto haciendo este código para probar, pero al ejecutarlo no me arroja nada, me podrían ayudar, por favor:

```
 ventas = {
    "Enero": 15000,
    "Febrero": 22000,
    "Marzo": 12000,
    "Abril": 17000,
    "Mayo": 81000,
    "Junio": 13000,
    "Julio": 21000,
    "Agosto": 41200,
    "Septiembre": 25000,
    "Octubre": 21500,
    "Noviembre": 91000,
    "Diciembre": 21000,
}
lista_meses=list(ventas)
valores = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] # prueba. la idea es que el usuario ingrese valores y después estos sean asignados al trimestre según posición
ventas_trimestre = dict(zip(lista_meses, valores))
quarters = {}
for mes, venta in ventas_trimestre.items():
    if mes == "Enero" and mes == "Febrero" and mes == "Marzo":
        q1 = valores[0]+valores[1]+valores[2]
        quarters[mes] = venta
quarters
```

Desde ya muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Bienvenido Francisco c: El resultado que esperas es que se muestre en la consola el diccionario ya armado?

Comment: Hola Dante,Sí, espero que quarters sea así: quarters{"q1":6,"q2":15,"q3":24,"q4":33} guiándome por la lista valores

Comment: Y como sería ventas_trimestre? Parece ser un diccionario.

Comment: me olvidé de agregar esta línea: ventas_trimestre = dict(zip(lista_meses, valores))

Comment: Podrías agregarla a la pregunta por favor?

Comment: Para mostrar el resultado en consola, tienes que usar el comando `print`, si no, no muestra nada en consola. Cambia la ultima linea de tu código por `print(quarters)` y te lo mostrará en la consola.

Comment: Pero más allá de eso (y no tiene que ver con tu duda), el código no te dará el resultado que esperas.

Comment: Va a resultar en `{"enero":1, "febrero":2, "marzo":3}`. En esta linea `quarters[mes] = venta` agregas al diccionario la clave mes y las ventas correspondiente a ese mes. Estás "copiando" una parte del diccionario original. Haces la suma de todas las ventas del trimestre, pero no haces nada con el resultado. Además de realizar esa misma suma 3 veces. Te recomiendo que replantees el código del bucle for.

Comment: muchas gracias, Dante. Saludos

Comment: De nada, saludos c:

Comment: @DanteS. No, de hecho el resultado es un diccionario vacío `{}` porque el `if` dentro del bucle no se cumple nunca, ya que `mes` siempre va a ser diferente a alguna de las cadenas  con que se compara, de modo que el `and` será `False`

Comment: Cierto @abulafia no se como no me percaté de eso, gracias por aclararlo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La verdad, no acabo de entender el papel que desempeñan tantas variables en tu programa, como el diccionario `ventas` que al final no se usa para nada, o la lista `lista_meses`, que tampoco se usa.

De hecho no veo ninguna necesidad de utilizar los nombres de los meses, ya que al final los trimestres se basan en la posición de los datos. Creo que al final el único dato de entrada que necesitas es la lista:

```
valores = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

A partir únicamente de esa lista es posible generar el diccionario que pides con algo como lo siguiente:

```
quarters = { f"q{i+1}": sum(valores[i*3:i*3+3]) for i in range(4) }
```

Esto produce el resultado:

```
{'q1': 6, 'q2': 15, 'q3': 24, 'q4': 33}
```

Corrígeme si se me ha escapado algo...

### Otra forma de hacer lo mismo

Si no estás cómodo con la sintaxis de *comprensión de diccionarios* que he usado o con los *slices*, puedes hacer un bucle "normal" y una suma "normal", obteniendo un código muy similar al que intentabas tú:

```
quarters = {}
for i in range(4):  # Los cuatro trimestres
  nombre_trimestre = "q{}".format(i+1)
  ventas_trimestre = valores[i*3] + valores[i*3+1] + valores[i*3+2]
  quarters[nombre_trimestre] = ventas_trimestre
```

El resultado sería el mismo

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu orientación y reducción del código. Saludos.